# How to resolve "Error: TypeScript compilation failed." issue in Gitlab CI?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, typescript, cicd, gitlab

I'm trying to learn to create a pipeline in Gitlab. All my tests fail because of the compilation issue. My code is included below along with the error message.

```
import loginPage from "../PageObjects/loginPage";

fixture('Login Tests')
.page('https://www.saucedemo.com/');

test('User Login to the website', async (t) => {
    await loginPage.loginWebsite('performance_glitch_user','secret_sauce');
});
```

```
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";

class loginPage{
    userName: Selector;
    password: Selector;
    loginBtn: Selector;
    pageName: Selector;
    
    constructor(){
        this.userName = Selector('#user-name');
        this.password = Selector('#password');
        this.loginBtn = Selector('#login-button');
        this.pageName = Selector('.title');
    }

    async loginWebsite(username, password){
        await t
        .typeText(this.userName, username)
        .typeText(this.password, password)
        .click(this.loginBtn)
        .expect(Selector(this.pageName).innerText).eql('Products');
    }
}

export default new loginPage;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testcafeproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Assignment",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome tests/**/*",
    "test2": "testcafe edge tests/**/*",
    "test:chrome:headless": "testcafe chrome:headless tests/**/*",
    "test:chrome:reports": "testcafe chrome tests/* --reporter html:reports/report.html",
    "test:chrome:reports:ss": "testcafe chrome tests/*.ts -s takeOnFails=true --reporter html:reports/report.html"
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "faker-js": "^1.0.0",
    "testcafe": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "testcafe-reporter-html": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

test_job:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test:chrome:headless
```

This is the error message in CI
[image: GITLAB ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

You might try deleting your modules directory all together and check the path to the class files in the ..\build directory, then rerun 'npm ci'